# How to access an object created in one class in another class

Tags: java

I am naive to java programming.

How to access an object created in one class into another class.

```
Class A
{
 Obj
}

Class B
{
 //Here i want to use Obj 
 A.Obj
}
```

For the above i declare Obj as public static, but when i use it in Class B as A.Obj, it is returning a syntax error saying

```
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field A.Obj".
```

Am i missing something here? Are there any other ways?

Comment: Please show some *real* code.  i.e. code that shows the `public static`.

Comment: Read about the meaning of "static", then you'll understand what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cant access without having an instance of A. You could do something like:

```
System.out.println(new A().Obj);//or define Obj as static in A class.
```

Note - You should encapsulate your Obj and access it via getter method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use provide a get method or use that object in static method as well. for your information static will not garbage collected unless the execution gets stopped for more about your answer [use this answer's reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231209/2749470)

Answer (score 0):

You need first to declare your Obj in class A as static

```
class A {
    static Object object = new Object();
}
```

Then you can use it

```
class B {
    A.object //in the class cannot be accessed directly
    Object x = A.object; //can use it to assign a value

    public Object Foo() {
       A.object //in a method can be accessed directly
       return A.object; //here as expression result
   }
}
```